# strategy for multi timeframe buy sell

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I want to develop strategy that give buy signal on price across above 30sma and sell signal price below 30sma moving average.

but in 1-minute time frame I want 5-minute time frame price and moving average cross over signal. means in in 1 min chart give buy/sell signal based on 5minute price and moving average crossover.

i try time frame expand feature but it not work in strategy function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note: The goal here is not to give or produce a strategy, but to show how can we use multi-timeframe series in pinescript

```
//@version=5
strategy("30SMA Crossover Strategy", overlay=true)


// 5 min timeframe
res_5 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "5", close)
sma30_5 = ta.sma(res_5, 30)

res_1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1", close)
sma5_1 = ta.sma(res_1, 5)  // This is not used , but just renamed to keep naming consistent

buy_signal = ta.crossover(sma30_5, res_1)
sell_signal = ta.crossunder(sma30_5, res_1)

if (buy_signal)
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long)
if (sell_signal)
    strategy.entry("Sell", strategy.short)

stop_loss = input.float(0.5, "Stop Loss %", step=0.1)
take_profit = input.float(1.5, "Take Profit %", step=0.1)
strategy.exit("Exit Buy", "Buy", stop=close*(1-stop_loss/100), limit=close*(1+take_profit/100))
strategy.exit("Exit Sell", "Sell", stop=close*(1+stop_loss/100), limit=close*(1-take_profit/100))

// Plot 30SMA and signals

plotshape(buy_signal, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, size=size.small)
plotshape(sell_signal, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, size=size.small)
```

Comment: Edited it . try now. Note: Pinescript is sensitive to indentations

Comment: thanks for reply but i want different  strategy and you make different i want 1min price close above 5min moving average (SMA-30) than buy. and 1min price close below 5min moving average(SMA-30) than sell .

Comment: @madhavladani you can take idea how can we use different timeframes in the pinescript.
res_5 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "5", close)
sma30_5 = ta.sma(res_5, 30)
Following becomes one minute series
res_1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1", close)
sma30_1 = ta.sma(res_1, 30)
Goal here is to demonstrate how different series can be used.

Comment: as per your instruction  i do but it got error and problem in loading

Comment: As per your instruction i do but it give false signal , here I do in 1 minute chart plot 5 and 30 min sma and generate buy and sell signal  - @Ganesh